# Parse an iframe using lxml

Tags: python, iframe, lxml

I am working on fetching the data from an <iframe>.
Then I want to get the data from <iframe> using `lxml`.

I did not found any resource from which we can fetch <iframe> from `lxml`.

Can anyone help me to let me know how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract `src` attribute from `iframe`, then fetch data from url by `urllib` and finally parse this data again using `lxml`.

Example code (not tested):

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring
data = urllib.urlopen(url) # fetching url with iframe
tree = fromstring(data.read()) # parsing tree to get src attribute
src_url = tree.cssselect("iframe").attrib['src']
data = urllib.urlopen(src_url) # open iframe src url
tree = fromstring(data.read()) # parsing iframe tree
```

Comment: what we have to use to fetch the src from iframe?

Answer (score 1):

We have find `src` attribute from `iframe`, then fetch data from `src` url by requests lib.

```
import lxml.html as lh
import requests


rq= requests.get(url)

content = rq.content

doc = lh.fromstring(content)

for i, elt in enumerate(doc.xpath('//[@id="page_content"]/div[2]/div/div/iframe')):

     url_data = elt.attrib.get('src')
     data = requests.get(url_data).content)
```